# vim: termguicolors with xterm-true-color still causing problems

Tags: vim, tmux, color-scheme, gnome-terminal, konsole

I have seen a multitiude of posts where not enabling 'tgc' with :

```
if exists('+termguicolors')
   let &t_8f =  "\<Esc>[38:2:%lu:%lu:%lum"
   let &t_8b =  "\<Esc>[48:2:%lu:%lu:%lum"
   " let &t_8f =  "\<Esc>[38:2;%lu;%lu;%lum" ( I have tried both ':' and ';' )
   " let &t_8b =  "\<Esc>[48:2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
   set t_Co=256
   set termguicolors
   " colorscheme gruvbox " color scheme
 endif
```

causes vim to have weird color output - usually with tmux.

Initially I found success with this too. Until one fine day (seriously!) vim starts behaving weird, but in a different way. It goes monochrome.

If, I don't set it, i.e `se notgc` , I actually get the right colorscheme. This is exactly the same in vim + tmux usage as well.

But, when I use vim + tmux, if I, say, kill a pane, or reload ~/tmux.config, existing vim sessions get weird again!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z02t2.png)
 is a look at one such occurance, the left is a newly opened buffer, while the right one, with the same settings, suddenly goes weird.

My settings :

- This is my company work server, I don't have su permissions.

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jul 15 10:13:09 UTC 2015
```

- VIM

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jul 26 2019 22:56:22)
Included patches: 1
Compiled by bob@c6x64
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
+balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers                                                                                               [25/126]
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
+clientserver      +job               -perl              +vertsplit
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +visual
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +wildignore
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +windows
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +writebackup
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +X11
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +xim
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xsmp_interact                                                                                         
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        +xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/tools/apps/local/vim/latest/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freety
pe2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -Wall -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc -std=gnu99   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixb
uf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lti
nfo -lelf -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm
```

The default cshrc had TERM explicitly set as `vt100`. If I change it to `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color`, I actually get good colorschemes within vim, and `:set term=$TERM` or explicitly to either of the above two, with the same problems showing up.

- TMUX
  v2.3, tried the following :

```
set -g default-terminal "screen/xterm-256color" 
set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
```

- I use gnome-terminal(v2.31.3), I also tried Konsole(v 2.3.3, Qt: 4.6.2, KDE: 4.3.4) -- and here I am not seeing the issue! But, konsole is terribly slow over my vnc connection, which is not the case gnome-terminal, so I decided to stick with it.

-- On color support : No true color support since

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    s="/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\"; s=s s s s s s s s;
    for (colnum = 0; colnum<77; colnum++) {
        r = 255-(colnum*255/76);
        g = (colnum*510/76);
        b = (colnum*255/76);
        if (g>255) g = 510-g;
        printf "\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", r,g,b;
        printf "\033[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", 255-r,255-g,255-b;
        printf "%s\033[0m", substr(s,colnum+1,1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}
```

returns [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaFyW.png)  where as Konsole returns a much smoother [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ieGB.png).

Should I ditch gnome-terminal and try some other emulator (which is snappier than Konsole) ? I would really appreciate if a solution can be found within gnome-terminal itself.

I hope I have given all the relevant details,
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following combination should work in most scenarios:

```
~/.vimrc:

" Inspect $TERM instad of t_Co as it works in neovim as well
if &term =~ '256color'
  " Enable true (24-bit) colors instead of (8-bit) 256 colors.
  " :h true-color
  if has('termguicolors')
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    set termguicolors
  endif
  colorscheme <your favorite colorscheme goes here>
endif
```

```
~/.tmux.conf:

# Set $TERM and force 256 colors.
# https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-256-colour-terminal
# https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-rgb-colour
if "[[ $TERM =~ 256color]]" "
    set -g default-terminal 'tmux-256color';
    set -ga terminal-overrides ',tmux-256color:Tc' "
```

Note that this **doesn't** hard-code any color configuration in `vim`, which is a clean approach. You should never have to force `vim` to use 256 color. The terminal is responsible to tell vim whether 256 colors are supported or not.

This approach also doesn't hard-code any color configuration in `tmux`. It may make sense to force tmux to use 256 color in some scenarios, though. If you want to do so, just remove the `if`:

```
~/.tmux.conf:

set -g default-terminal 'tmux-256color'
set -ga terminal-overrides ',tmux-256color:Tc'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is in part due to your tmux configuration.  You'll want to set the following in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
set -ag terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

Note that you cannot use a slash in the default terminal option, since it must be a valid terminal type.  I assume all the systems you are logging into have the `screen-256color` terminal type, but you can check by running `infocmp screen-256color`, which should print terminal info on success and an error on error.  You may need to install additional packages to add that terminal type.

As far as GNOME Terminal, 2.31 is very old. The VTE version used in GNOME 2 definitely does not support true colors.  Ideally you'll set up your local system to use a modern terminal emulator and log in over SSH instead of using VNC, and things will work.

I will be clear that since you're using CentOS or RHEL 6 here, that virtually any terminal emulator you're trying to use will likely be broken.  This OS is a decade old and will lose security support as of November.  Your best bet, as mentioned, is to use a more modern environment on your laptop or desktop and log in over SSH.

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest suggest some modern environment to use ? I can only get access to intranet via company laptop, which is windows. I typically have to deal with a lot of GUI apps as well ... Is PuTTy + Xming still a good choice ?

PS: I did not actually put a '/' in `default-terminal` for .tmux.conf, It was only to indicate I tried both. and infocmp did not error out in Gnome terminal. Also, what puzzles me is the vim + tmux setup was working just fine with :se tgc up until yesterday!

Comment: Update: I tried using mobaxterm , used my wsl ubuntu shell to ssh into my server and open vim ... I see the same issue exists here as well. I suspect this is purely a vim issue .. can any plugins cause it?

Comment: The standard terminal for WSL should be fine, provided you're using the latest version.  I'd test a local tmux and Vim configuration and then try one logging into the remote host.  Check the `TERM` environment variable is set appropriately as well.

Comment: The local tmux + vim looks amazing even with default colorscheme. In my local, by default, TERM is xterm-256color. and in vim `set term=$(TERM)`. If I try to replicate this in my work server, vim shows good colors, but only if `set notgc`. in `se tgc`, I get the same issue as before. Problem is, while loading tmux, `se notgc` is glitchy as mentioned before.

Comment: Also, for my remote, the global .cshrc setting involved putting TERM as `vt100`. But, to install tmux without sudo, I had to install libeven 2.1.8 and ncurses-6.0. With this, I could use `xterm-256color` and `screen-256color`. Could it be that somehow these got corrupted ?

Comment: It's possible that those terminal types are not a part of the core set of terminal types shipped to all systems, and adding the full `ncurses` package may provide additional ones.